# Auto start video recording

Tags: android, android-studio

I was using following code to start video recording

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button record;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

record = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
record.performClick();

}
public void onClick(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,300);

    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}
}
```

but in this following code it launches video screen but user have to click record button to record video but i want to auto start video recording on start thanks and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are not associating your onClick method with  button. Also performClick can only be used after layout is fully inflated, not in onCreate method. Instead you should start your recording directly (see code below).

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button record;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    record = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {
          startRecording();
       }
    });
    startRecording();
}

private void startRecording(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,300);

    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}
}
```